# Session features in php? Preventing multiple login in same browser

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have issue in sessions if i login as **user1** for the first time and if open a new tab and login as **user2** for the second time, User 2 is able to  view all the pages of user1 privileges  , How to overcome this issue in php? how to show display the first as **login page** if the **user2** goes to first tab that is **user1**

```
   $this->is_logged_in();
        $this->clear_cache();
    }
    function is_logged_in() 
    {
        $is_logged_in = $this -> session -> userdata('is_logged_in');
        if (!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true)
        {
            //redirect('/www.XXXX.ae');
        }
    }
    function clear_cache()
    {
        $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform,max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        $this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
    }

function logout()
    {           
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        $this->session->set_userdata('userId',"");
        $this->session->set_userdata('password',"");   
        $this->session->set_userdata('role',"");   
        $rurl = $this->session->userdata('rurl');
            redirect($rurl,'refresh');

    }

function login()
    { 
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        $this->session->set_userdata('userId',"");
        $this->session->set_userdata('password',"");   
        $this->session->set_userdata('role',"");   
        $username   =   $this->input->post('username');
        $password   =   $this->input->post('password');
        .......
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're not resetting the session variable after **user2** logs in.

Comment: i have but the user2 can access the user1 page

Comment: what happens when you do a `var_dump()` on `$_SESSION` when a user logs in?

Comment: i wil post u the var_dump() result

Comment: @Matt bool(false) {"result":true,"url":"home"}  var_dump output

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you destroy the session id cookie (I assume you are using cookies to store session ID)  and unset the $_SESSION superglobal upon a user logout.

It also seems a bit unclear in your question whether a logged in user is able to log in directly as another user without logging out.  Typically in most applications you would want to have a specific logout before even giving the user a new login prompt.  However, if your application needs to allow a login change for an already logged in user, you would also need to destroy the session cookie and variable on login change.

Comment: @Mike Brant!!! yup that was my query!!! how to destory the session cookie on login change !!! what are the changes to be done in my code for the above code!!

Comment: @dude I don't know as you haven't shown your whole logic.  I don't see anything there relative to user logout functionality.

Comment: @dude You should also include your session class, since that is where the magic happens it would seem :)

Comment: @MikeBrant  i didnt get u can u explain m??

Comment: @dude It seems that your sess_destroy function in your session class is actually what needs to be looked at, since I assume this is where you would actually be killing the session. You should include it in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, the trick here is to hide the login form when a user is logged in! That is when the base_url() which I think calls your login function is called and the user is logged in, it redirects to the application, not the login screen. I hope this helps!